# Write logs to specifc file in linux

Tags: linux, debian, logs, configuration, rsyslog

I have logs coming from my stormshield firewall to my debian server looking like this :

```
92.168.2.253 → 12.12.4.58   Syslog 758 USER.WARNING: 1 2021-12-22T10:45:38+01:00 FW-STORMSHIELD asqd - - - \357\273\277id=firewall time="2021-12-22 10:45:38" fw="FW-STORMSHIELD" tz=+0100 startime="2021-12-22 10:45:35" pri=4 confid=01 slotlevel=2 ruleid=56 rulename="17b8311aa81_10e" srcif="Ethernet5" srcifname="DMZ-OPENVPN" ipproto=tcp dstif="Ethernet0" dstifname="internet" proto=ssl src=192.168.13.153 srcport=64722 srcportname=port-tcp-sup srcname=P-WINSAV-007-alegal srcmac=00:0c:22:12:fd:82 dst=145.240.201.174 dstport=443 dstportname=https dstname=drive.google.com dstcontinent="na" dstcountry="us" modsrc=96.35.166.98 modsrcport=27922 ipv=4 action=block msg="ChangeCipherSpec trop t\303\264t" class=protocol classification=0 alarmid=312 target=dst repeat=2 l
```

I don't have access to the Stormshield firewall configuration and I can't figure out to which file they are written to on my server.

If possible, I would like to write them to a specific file

I tried this configuration in the rsylog.conf file :

```
$template DynamicFile,"/var/log/syslogclients/%fromhost%-syslog.log"
*.* ?DynamicFile
```

to dynamically create a log file and write in it every time I receive logs, but the file remains empty.

I've restarted `rsyslog`. What else am I missing?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes I did, but it is still not working.

Comment: Possibly related:  https://serverfault.com/questions/740307/logging-in-separates-files-in-rsyslog  (1st answer) and  https://serverfault.com/questions/383530/rsyslog-how-do-i-direct-messages-from-all-remote-machines-to-one-file (top rated answer)

Comment: Thank you, the topics are very similar indeed. It didn't work for me tho. A way to work around this issue would be to understand where these logs are written instead, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Note that some rules may short-circuit others. A rule with `stop` will discard of the input, effectively cancelling any later rules.  To debug why this doesn't work, I suggest: 1) put your rule first, at the top of `/etc/rsyslog.conf` so it has precedence over other rules 2) use tips for trouble-shooting:  https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/troubleshooting/index.html#typical-problems. rsyslog configuration looks complex. If you manage to make it work, please share what you learned by self-answering your Q.